# database.yml deployment best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I don't check my database.yml file into source control and I was wondering what others do/best practice for copying this file over to the server when deploying.

I use Capistrano for deployment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently, I keep a shared folder called shared that lives outside of my deply_to dirs.  I keep my database.yml and other config files there and have a hook in cap to cp those over during deployment.  Here is my simple cap task for doing the copy:

```
after "deploy:update_code","deploy:config_symlink"

namespace :deploy do

  task :config_symlink do
    run "cp #{shared_path}/../../shared/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end
```

Comment: This is fairly common, and can keep some production passwords out of source control. I'm not sure why you're backing out of shared_path, though. And I would ln rather than cp.

Comment: I back out of shared because shared is at the deploy_dir level.  I usually have multiple installs of the app such as beta and prod which use the same config.  If you only have one deployment then yah you can just use the shared_path dir of the deploy target.

Comment: @JakeDempsey And how you do it if the differents instal app have differents config files?

Answer (score 9):

My deployment script was breaking using the `after "deploy:update_code"` hook because that step seemed to be trying to access the DB already.  So I do:

```
before "deploy:assets:precompile", 'deploy:symlink_shared'

namespace :deploy do

  task :symlink_shared do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been beating my head on this one for quite some time, and have figured out an easier solution for **Capistrano 3**. Hope this helps those out there.

I couldn't for the life of me get the "run" or "execute" commands to work in my deploy.rb file. As it turns out, in **Capistrano 3**, you should put your database.yml underneath the deployment_directory/shared folder. Then, in your deployment.rb file, include the file in the linked_files variable and it automatically gets symlinked to the same path during deployment.

Here's an example:

For starters, I don't have database.yml checked into source control. My database.yml is located here on the production server:

var/www/myapp/shared/config/database.yml

In my deployment.rb, I've added this line

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
```

During the deployment, capistrano automatically symlinks the file to:

var/www/myapp/current/config/database.yml

Hope this helps others out there. I've really been beating my head on the wall on this today.