# rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rake, capistrano, dbmigrate

Why we get an error on the command rake db:migrate

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/mahaloo/mahaloo/releases/20120329200051/log/development.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

rake aborted!
unable to open database file

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Whats wrong there. I tryed to deploy via capistrano, i used this tutorial to setup capistrano http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/basic-deployment-with-capistrano/

Answer (score 1):

You're either missing the log directory or file. Have you run cap deploy:setup ?

Otherwise manually create the log file first.

Comment: Thanks @Isotope i touched the development.log and set the r/w-rights to 0666, but rake aborted always.

Comment: If you don't have write to the log dir then `cap deploy:check` will fail.  Of course, you already ran `cap deploy:setup` and `cap deploy:check`, and fix any problems.  You're might be missing the database.yml because it's not in scm, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you're following the practice of not checking your database.yml into source control.  If that is the case, you can make a copy of your database.yml in your deploy `shared/config` folder, and create a Capistrano task to symlink that back into your release folder.  Something like this (in `namespace deploy`)

```
task :create_symlinks do
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/db/production.sqlite3 #{release_path}/db/production.sqlite3"
  run " -nfs #{shared_path}/config/ldap.yml #{release_path}/config/ldap.yml"
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```

Then call this in a hook

```
after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:create_symlinks"
after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:migrate"
```

I think that would work, that's how we're step up on our project.  This is similar to these questions:

[database.yml deployment best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785104/database-yml-deployment-best-practice)
[Capistrano - can't deploy my database.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684649/capistrano-cant-deploy-my-database-yml)
[How to manage Rails database.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449836/how-to-manage-rails-database-yml)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with `sudo` if your enviroment its on linux, for example, i got that error trying to run the migration, `rake db:migrate`, so i used `sudo rake db:migrate` and that's work, maybe because the rake when its trying to consult development.log doesn't have the right permissions or something like that.